# How to handle or execute large SQL script (5gb) in Mysql workbench

Tags: mysql

I have received a large SQL script from another company in order to migrate it, it's around 5GB, It was very difficult to open that script on MySql workbench because it keeps hanging when I import the script file and try to execute it.

Eventually, I could Import it and execute it, but I faced some syntax errors and I couldn't fix them because it was very hard to scroll that large script.

So what I need is a way to handle this issue, or a way to split that large SQL script file into several scripts and then I will work with each file separately

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this is an old question, but for the benefit of anyone else landing here after a Google search (as I did) - couldn't you just use:

`mysql -u [username] -p [database] < \path\to\scriptFile.sql`

...instead of trying to open the file in MySqlWorkbench?

Comment: I can confirm I have done this with 20+ gb databases